# Why does a Hermitian operator have a basis of its own eigenvectors?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, eigenvalue, observables

Suppose I have a *hermitian operator* $\Omega$. The proof of the existence of a orthonormal eigenbasis as given in **Shankar** is given.

> [image]

What I don't understand is why the second eigenvector $\left| \omega_2 \right> $ of matrix $\Omega$ belongs to the subspace $V^{n-1}_{\perp 1}$ orthogonal to the first eigenvector $\left| \omega_1 \right> $?

Answer (score 1):

Hints: One should use the facts that:

1. Eigenvectors for different eigenvalues of a Hermitian operator are orthogonal, cf. e.g. [this](https://en.citizendium.org/wiki/Hermitian_operator) webpage.
2. If the eigenvalues are the same one can choose appropriate linear combinations of the eigenvectors to be orthogonal.

Comment: I had my doubt regarding this proof from the book. Of course, if eigenvalues are different and eigenvectors are orthogonal as a consequence, the proof becomes easy. But my doubt is the one mentioned in the question above.